# How do i run the equivalent of single configuration import from a hook?

Tags: views, 8, importing-exporting, configuration

I have a hook_update_N that is changing a field.  It is deleting the field and recreating it with the same name but a different field, formatter, and widget.

The problem I'm having is that there is a view that is using my field and when I delete my field the view is being deleted and my site then throws an error.

I have the views.view.view_name.yml file saved in a directory.  Is there a function or set of  functions that will import the view from that file?

Comment: When deleting a field, one view that contains that field shouldn't be deleted by the system, but instead, showing on it's configuration page, that the field above is missing. Are you sure about this behavior? Sounds odd to me.

Comment: I thought so too, but here i am without the view.  I am 100% sure about the behavior.  I managed to reimport the view and the site now loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('views') && !View::load('view_name')) {
    $config_path = DRUPAL_ROOT.'/configurationpathto/views_view_view_name.yml';
    $data = Yaml::parse($config_path);
    \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('views.view.view_name')->setData($data)->save(TRUE);
  }
```